# How to Save and Recover All Sessions of Users in a Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I am developing a system in which I need to recover all or logged onto the server with active users.

Context: When the user logs in and creates a session, keep in the database with their information logon date and time of the session.

Session ["example"] = example;

When the user logs off I drop the session and I change the information in the database. Following this structure can have "hands on" all logged in users. The problem that occurs to me is when the user is left with idle time and the session drops automatically or when the user closes the browser. Thus can not change its status in the database.

?????

I wonder if there is a way to retrieve all active session on a server, or retrieve all users that are still logged into the system and that their sessions have not expired?

Has anyone ever managed to do something similar?

Comment: Have you looked into OnSessionStart and OnSessionEnd events? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can never tell when a user has abandoned their session.  You need Signal R.